# TYPO3 Powermail file name for attachment from variables

Tags: pdf, typo3, attachment, powermail

I have used the extension: pdfviewhelpers to create a PDF from my Powermail form for download. The name of the PDF is generated from 2 variables {name} and {firstname} and stored in the TYPO3 backend in a folder fileadmin/PDF/xxx{name}_{firstname}.pdf.

Now I'm trying to send this PDF via email attachment to the user, but I can't get it to work. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: This should be possible via `plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.sender.addAttachment`. It's of type cObj, so you can insert data/variables. https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermail/blob/develop/Configuration/TypoScript/Main/Configuration/04_MailSender.typoscript#L69